# How to automate Office 2013 on Windows 8.1 App Store Application

Tags: windows-8.1

I'm try to develop a Windows 8.1 App Store Application.
But i facing an issue how to integrate Office Automation with it.
Can someone advise me how to do Office Automation for Windows 8.1 App Store Application.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly create an Office developer account. 
In Solution Explorer by selecting Add->Connected Service select office 365 dont select files as you would require an OneDrive for Business account.  Once signed in with Office 365 credentials, adding a service to the project is as easy as selecting the appropriate service and applying the required permissions.
Visual studio will now start adding the required files.